# How would you find all unitary matrices of square matrix A such that A^(2)=A?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So far what I did is:

U U* A^(2) U U*=U U* A

I A^(2) I= I A  (since U* U=U U*=I)

Then A^(2)=A.

So am I on the right track?

Comment: I'm a little unclear on your question.  Is A unitary, or is A somehow related to a matrix U which is unitary?  If so, how is it related?

Comment: Yes A unitary. all unitary matrices A∈Mn,( Mn meaning square matrix)

Comment: A basic point— the only idempotent element in a group is the identity element

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is unitary, then $AA^*=A^*A=I$.  And by assumption, $A^2=A$.  That should be the starting point for the problem.  At least, if I understand your question correctly.  If you have introduced a new matrix $U$, then you have gone off the path.

Answer (score 2):

I assume the question is finding $A\in M(n,\mathbb{F})$: $A$ is unitary and $A^2=A$.

We have $0=A^2-A=A(A-E_n)$ where $E_n$ is unit matrix of $M(n,\mathbb{F})$, so $0=A^{-1}A(A-E_n)$ then $A=E_n$

Answer (score 1):

Unitary matrices are by definition invertible, and the only invertible idempotent matrix is the identity matrix, so *a fortiori* the only unitary idempotent matrix is the identity.